Another issue with entering user name and password using Selenium
I am trying to scrape the data from a URL on my home network that, (I think) is populated with data by Javascript. The URL is password protected, and I need to fill in the user name and password with this form to access it:

I found this answer to a similar question on Stack Overflow and adapted the code slightly as follows:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = 'http://192.168.42.57'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'username'))).send_keys("xxx")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'password'))).send_keys("yyy")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()

xxx and yyy represent the correct user name and password.  When I run this, the log in window shown above appears and I have to manually fill in the user name and password, then get timed out with the following error:
File "R:\Private\Python\sandbox\web_scrape_v2.py", line 24, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'username'))).send_keys("xxx")

  File "C:\WinPython\WPy64-3940\python-3.9.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 105, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

I tried inspecting the source for the log-in form, to check that I was addressing the correct elements on the webpage, but I don't seem to be able to do this. I would appreciate any suggestions you might have.

Does this answer your question? How to Handle Authentication alert of browser in selenium webdriver?

You're not dealing with HTML but with the "alert"'ish prompt for authentication, usually you can auth by sending username and password in the url like https://username:password@hostname.com/restrictedPage

Hi @Daviid - yes, that does seem to work - thank you!  I deleted all the "wait" code and the timeout error disappeared.  Now just need to work out how to sift through the URL code to find the data I need
